# Update cached data using Apollo Client - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to build a HackerNews Clone using ReactJs, GraphQL, and NodeJs, and so far I was able to implement many things, but I'm stuck while trying to update my links in order for the user to see the changes without having to update the page. The two queries related to this process is the mutation VOTE_MUTATION, which gives the user the possibility to vote the links in my query LINKS_FEED. It works, but I have to refresh the page to see the changes. Here's what I tried to do

Queries

mutation VOTE_MUTATION

```
export const VOTE_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation VoteMutation($linkId: ID!) {
    vote(linkId: $linkId) {
      id
      link {
        id
        votes {
          id
          user {
            id
          }
        }
      }
      user {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

query LINKS_FEED

```
export const LINKS_FEED = gql`
  query LinksFeed {
    feed {
      count
      links {
        id
        description
        url
        postedBy {
          id
          name
        }
        votes {
          id
          user {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And this is what my API call looks like

```
 const [upvoteLink, { data }] = useMutation(VOTE_MUTATION);

  const voteLink = async (linkId) => {
    try {
      await upvoteLink({
        variables: { linkId },
        update: (cache, { upvoteLink }) => {
          const currentData = cache.readQuery({ query: LINKS_FEED });
          const newData = {...currentData}
          newData.feed = {...currentData.feed}
          newData.feed.links = [...currentData.feed.links, upvoteLink];
          cache.writeQuery({ query: LINKS_FEED }, newData);
        },
      });
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err.message);
    }
  };
```

Comment: the same data object used (updates checked/detected by ref) ... do it immutable way... new data, new feed, new links

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Comment: `const newData = {...data}; newData.feed = { ...data.feed}; newData.feed.links ......` if feed is an object

Comment: So where do I update the cache in your example?

Comment: `cache.writeQuery({ query: LINKS_FEED }, newData);` of course?

Comment: It didn't work, I still have to refresh the page...

Comment: console.log data, upvotelink and newData ... compare structure/elements